# How to disable the button in vue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to make a question solving screen using v-window. I keep my questions in a questionlist array. Clicking on the next button moves to the next window. I don't want it to go back to the beginning when it comes to the last question. I wrote clickable for this and bind it with disabled on the button. But when i do this, my button is disabled directly.

```
<v-btn @click="next" :disabled="clickable" v-model="terms">
                <v-icon x-large>mdi-arrow-right-thick</v-icon>
 </v-btn>


 
 methods: {
    next() {
      this.onboarding =
        this.onboarding + 1 === this.length ? 0 : this.onboarding + 1;
    },
  },

watch: {
    clickable: function () {
      const length = this.questionList.length;
      if (this.onboarding == length) {
        return !this.terms;
      }
      return this.terms;
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use a computed as

```js
computed: {
  clickable: function() {
    return (this.onboarding === this.questionList.length) ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Then you can check and modification as your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a watcher, but a computed property instead, because you want the value of `clickable` to be reactive based on changes. It does not make sense to have return statements on the watcher, and binding a watcher in your template will always return a truthy value.

Therefore, computed property is the way to go:

```
computed: {
    clickable: function () {
        const length = this.questionList.length;
        if (this.onboarding == length) {
            return !this.terms;
        }
        return this.terms;
    },
},
```

The documentation has a guide on [when to use computed property vs watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property).